# Javascript: Math formula too long to calculate correctly?

Tags: javascript, wolfram-mathematica, calculator

I'm using quite a long formula to calculate a specific value from 4 input numbers. It works perfectly in JSFiddle but the result isn't right on my website for some reason. It only works when the value M is greater than 15, then it gets reset to 15. So

```
4<=M<=15
0<q<1
0<W
0<S
```

where M is the maximum spree, S is the score, q is the killing propability and W is the number of wins.

This **should** give me a value between 0 and 1, but it's very often over 1000...

Here the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ogonu9e9/

You can try different values but remember the rules from above and don't go to low with q or M.

On my website: http://zcatch-ranking.com/

Just click on a name and then expand

I got the formula with Mathematica.

**CODE**

```
M = 14;
S = 145.46;
if (M > 15) {
  M = 15;
}
W = 61;
q = 0.574;
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'S=' + S + ' W=' + W + ' q=' + q + ' M=' + M;

function expand() {
  $('#expand').remove();
  var p = (-2 * (-675 * Math.pow((-1 + q), 2) * S + (192 - 2 * (-52 + 61 * M) * q + (4 - 13 * M + 15 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(q, 2)) * W) + (2 * Math.pow(2, (1 / 3)) * (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 2) * W * (2025 * (-5 + M) * (-1 + q) * (-5 + (-1 + M) * q) * S + (42 * Math.pow(M, 3) * Math.pow(q, 2) - 3 * Math.pow(M, 2) * q * (113 + 22 * q) - 4 * (121 + 13 * q + Math.pow(q, 2)) + M * (841 + 217 * q + 25 * Math.pow(q, 2))) * W)) / Math.pow((-(-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 3) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 6075 * (2260 - 1337 * M + 177 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * S * W + 2 * (20176 - 52424 * M + 18757 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + 3 * (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 4) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 2025 * (-900 + 1225 * M - 654 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 89 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * S * W + (-1168 + 4856 * M - 5521 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 4551 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + 3 * Math.pow(3, 1 / 2) * Math.pow((-(-5 + M) * Math.pow((-4 + M), 2) * Math.pow(q, 6) * Math.pow(W, 2) * Math.pow((-225 * Math.pow((-1 + q), 3) * S + (-64 + (-52 + 61 * M) * q + (-4 + 13 * M - 15 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(q, 2) + Math.pow(M, 3) * Math.pow(q, 3)) * W), 2) * (-1366875 * Math.pow((-6 + M), 2) * (-5 + M) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 12150 * (80 - 176 * M - 13 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 9 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * S * W + (-336 + 2552 * M - 8125 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 8789 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * Math.pow(W, 2))), 1 / 2) - 3 * (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 5) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 2025 * (420 - 889 * M + 396 * Math.pow(M, 2) - 122 * Math.pow(M, 3) + 15 * Math.pow(M, 4)) * S * W + (-208 + 1544 * M - 4957 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 4758 * Math.pow(M, 3) - 39 * Math.pow(M, 4)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 6) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 6075 * (-20 + 89 * M - 157 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 58 * Math.pow(M, 3) - 11 * Math.pow(M, 4) + Math.pow(M, 5)) * S * W + (32 - 304 * M + 1298 * Math.pow(M, 2) - 2646 * Math.pow(M, 3) + 2421 * Math.pow(M, 4) - 243 * Math.pow(M, 5)) * Math.pow(W, 2))), (1 / 3)) + Math.pow(2, (2 / 3)) * Math.pow((-(-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 3) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 6075 * (2260 - 1337 * M + 177 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * S * W + 2 * (20176 - 52424 * M + 18757 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + 3 * (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 4) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 2025 * (-900 + 1225 * M - 654 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 89 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * S * W + (-1168 + 4856 * M - 5521 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 4551 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + 3 * Math.pow(3, 1 / 2) * Math.pow((-(-5 + M) * Math.pow((-4 + M), 2) * Math.pow(q, 6) * Math.pow(W, 2) * Math.pow((-225 * Math.pow((-1 + q), 3) * S + (-64 + (-52 + 61 * M) * q + (-4 + 13 * M - 15 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(q, 2) + Math.pow(M, 3) * Math.pow(q, 3)) * W), 2) * (-1366875 * Math.pow((-6 + M), 2) * (-5 + M) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 12150 * (80 - 176 * M - 13 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 9 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * S * W + (-336 + 2552 * M - 8125 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 8789 * Math.pow(M, 3)) * Math.pow(W, 2))), 1 / 2) - 3 * (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 5) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 2025 * (420 - 889 * M + 396 * Math.pow(M, 2) - 122 * Math.pow(M, 3) + 15 * Math.pow(M, 4)) * S * W + (-208 + 1544 * M - 4957 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 4758 * Math.pow(M, 3) - 39 * Math.pow(M, 4)) * Math.pow(W, 2)) + (-4 + M) * Math.pow(q, 6) * W * (1366875 * (30 - 11 * M + Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(S, 2) + 6075 * (-20 + 89 * M - 157 * Math.pow(M, 2) + 58 * Math.pow(M, 3) - 11 * Math.pow(M, 4) + Math.pow(M, 5)) * S * W + (32 - 304 * M + 1298 * Math.pow(M, 2) - 2646 * Math.pow(M, 3) + 2421 * Math.pow(M, 4) - 243 * Math.pow(M, 5)) * Math.pow(W, 2))), (1 / 3))) / (6 * (-225 * Math.pow((-1 + q), 3) * S + (-64 + (-52 + 61 * M) * q + (-4 + 13 * M - 15 * Math.pow(M, 2)) * Math.pow(q, 2) + Math.pow(M, 3) * Math.pow(q, 3)) * W));
  $('#expanded').html('</br><hr style="margin-top:40px;"></br>Test ' + p)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="text">
</div>
<button onclick="expand()" type="button" id="expand">
  expand
</button>
<span id="expanded">
```

Comment: Please read through [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) **in** the question.

Comment: okay i updated the question although its all on the jsfiddle file and it doesnt really make a difference how the formula looks exactly and the structure is quite simple @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Whether it's simple or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Innerw0lf Since your code contains lots of 7 digit constants, like 1366875, since you say the code fails on some sized numbers, since you have lots of powers and products, since documentation on js says it limits constants to 2^53 which is only 9*10^15 I am guessing you might have an overflow issue buried somewhere in all your powers. If you could edit your code to include a particular example M,q,W,S that fails and an almost identical example M,q,W,S that works then I might be able to track down the biggest intermediate value or one of your roots that fails in one and works in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps change your assigning method

```
4<=M<=15
0<q<1
0<W
0<S
```

try

> nested if

like below example it can help you

```
if(4<=M)
  if(M<=15)
    ...
```

if you still want use in single line gates(AND gate)
 hope it is useful.

Comment: no these aren't really implemented in my code, these are just to show you what numbers you can use in the jsfiddle. so it just has to look for the case where M is greater than 15, but it can't be below 4!

Comment: have you check the database,if the uploaded data type different means it will result like that check everything(code and database config file as well.